# Floats, doubles and half floats

Tags: opengl, floating-point, double

I was wondering about how bits are organized on floats (4 bytes), double (8 bytes) and half floats (2 bytes, used on OpenGL implementation).

Further, how I could convert from one to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence for each of these formats, you have:

- 1 sign bit
- x exponent bits yielding a whole number E
- y mantissa (or "significand") bits yielding a fractional number M

If the sign bit is 1, the number is negative, else it is positive.

To get the magnitude, you take (1 + M) * 2^(E - k), where k (called the "exponent bias") depends on the format.

It's worth noting that certain combinations of sign, exponent, and mantissa are "special" values, like 0, `-inf`, `+inf`, and `NaN`.

For the specifics (values of x, y, and k) see Wikipedia for [single precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) (4 bytes), [double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) (8 bytes), and [half precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format) (2 bytes).

Note that these are all specified by [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard), so googling that might give you helpful results. :)

Comment: GPU's may not be fully conformant to IEEE 754 (for example they frequently omit support for denormals)

Answer (score 1):

[Half](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format), [Single](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format), [Double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)

Handy-dandy diagrams on those pages. The library should provide means for converting between the various formats.